# Visual Studio TFS Plugin - How to register page?

Tags: plugins, tfs, visual-studio-2015

I would like to develop a TFS plugin that displays a simple page in the Team Explorer. To do this, I loosely followed [this project](https://github.com/ajryan/WorkItemSearchReplace). I'm able to register a menu command, but when the command is invoked my page that I derive from TeamExplorerPageBase is unknown to the Team Explorer. The code to load the page is:

```
var teamExplorer = (ITeamExplorer)(this.ServiceProvider.GetService(typeof(ITeamExplorer)));
teamExplorer.NavigateToPage(new Guid(BiscomTfsLabelPage.Id), null);
```

the call to NavigateToPage returns an error:
[image]

So how do I register the page with Team Explorer??

UPDATE:
Looks like it's an issue with the debugger, because when I run the VSIX file that gets output by the build, then open a new instance of Visual Studio it works:
[image]

So now I'd really like to know if there's a way that I can debug the extension, since it doesn't seem to register the page if I use the debugger.

Answer (score 0):

Since it works in a new instance of Visual Studio. You could try to debug it with a new opened Visual Studio.

Go to the properties of your  project and look under the debug tab, find a Start Action. Select to "Start external program" and browse to where you have visual studio installed. C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe 
[image]

Comment: That's how they have it set up, with a command line argument of /rootsuffix Exp. When I run the debugger it appears as though VS installed the extension (the menu command shows up), but I get the "page not found" error. What I'm doing now is I removed the command line argument, I build the solution, run the installer (uninstalling the extension first, if I have to), then running the debugger and it works. This is a huge pain though because uninstalling and reinstalling the extension manually is too time consuming and not maintainable, it's just a dirty hack until we figure out something better